# mySQL LEFT JOIN total number of results from MATCH query

Tags: mysql, sql, full-text-search, left-join, match

I have two tables which are:

```
## search_queries ##
id | user_input | count
1  | "term"     | 80
```

and mad_product_searchindex which contains a FULLTEXT index of (Brand, Shortdesc and Keywords)

This is the query that is run on our search page

```
SELECT *,
        MATCH(Brand, ShortDesc, Keywords) AGAINST('$search_term' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS score
        FROM mad_product_searchindex
        WHERE MATCH(Brand, ShortDesc, Keywords) AGAINST('$search_term' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
        AND DisplayItem = "1" and product_variant_main = "0"
        GROUP BY CatalogueRef
        ORDER BY score
```

I want to produce a report from the search_queries which will iterate through the table and run this above query and return the total number of products matched as an extra column.

I've gotten close, however it only works if I hard-code in the $search_term as e.g 'term' which obviously only then works for a single row.

```
SELECT search_queries.user_input AS user_search, count AS searched, count(Results.Totals)
FROM search_queries
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Totals, 0 AS Bonus,
MATCH(Brand, ShortDesc, Keywords) AGAINST(user_search IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS score

        FROM mad_product_searchindex 

        WHERE MATCH(Brand, ShortDesc, Keywords) AGAINST(user_search IN BOOLEAN MODE)

        AND DisplayItem = "1" and product_variant_main = "0"

        GROUP BY CatalogueRef

        ORDER BY score DESC
) Results ON 0 = Results.Bonus
WHERE 1=1

GROUP BY user_input
```

I've tried aliasing user_search, and typing in the table.column name. Neither work, brings back an error saying it can't find that column (presumably because it's looking in mad_product_searchindex.) How can i specify that column as a variable? ... Or have i gone down the completely wrong route with this?

Basically getting to

```
id | user_input | count | returned results
1  | "term"     | 80    | 51
```